# Automatically substituting logos in web images

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Consider the following task:

- Open a given URL
- Find the first image tag in the URL
- Substitute it for an image in your local drive
- Save the resulting webpage as a png

I want to automatize this task with a Python script, and I am unsure of the best approach.

I have been using selenium to convert URLs into screenshots, but I am unsure of how to introduce the part about modifying the first image tag to load a local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `execute_script` to replace the image should look something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.aircanada.com/en/'
browser.get(url)

my_image = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pagePromoBanner-wrapper"]/div/a/img')

# or
# my_image = browser.find_element_by_xpath('any XPath')

link_to_new_image = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
# if you are using python 3.6 and up:
browser.execute_script(f"arguments[0].src = '{link_to_new_image}'", my_image )
# else:
# browser.execute_script("arguments[0].src = '"+link_to_new_image+"'", my_image )
```

Hope this helps you!